# Как перестроить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Снимки с разрешением не хуже чем один метр, что гарантирует высокую достоверность.

Comment: Разрешение — количество точек на единицу площади, а не длина в метрах. Оно бывает большим или меньшим, выше или ниже. Не хуже и лучше, а оптимальным или нет. Всякое разрешение хорошо, когда уместно для передачи посредством сети, например.

Comment: "Количество точек" - частная количественная характеристика из области компьютерной графики и характеризует параметры растра разложения изображения каким-либо цифровым устройством. В фотографии и телевидении разрешение системы (с доцифровой эпохи это не менялось) измеряется количеством **различимых** (глазом или измерительными методами) _оптических или телевизионных линий_ на длину растра изображения, равную его высоте (приведённую к формату кадра).

Comment: Пересчет разрешаемого количества линий в линейные метры через масштаб изображения **абсолютно корректен**. Поскольку "высокому" разрешению при этом соответствует меньшее численное значение, то и говорят "не хуже".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разрешение - это термин используемый в картографии, связанный с масштабом.

> Разрешение карты напрямую связано с ее масштабом. По мере уменьшения масштаба карты разрешение уменьшается, границы элементов должны быть сглажены, упрощены или просто не должны быть отражены.

> Разрешение карты определяется минимальными размерами объектов, которые могут быть отображены на карте данного масштаба. Из Студопедия.

*Разрешение - в русском имеет значение позволение, но вообще это слово скорее относится к пониманию и разрешению дела определенным образом. Разрешить - дать делу ход. Решенный - понятный, внятный. Вообще решить - это уже resolute(resolution переводят разрешение), уже содержит приставку ре-, шить - это связывать, скреплять, соединять. Решить - связать, понять. А РАЗ+решить, это масло масляное, если считать, что раз=ре.*

Карта должна быть понятной для изображенных объектов размером в 1 метр.

Меня еще смущает подчиненная часть "что гарантирует высокую достоверность." Я бы убрал все эти "не хуже", "высокую" - бесполезные оценки перегружающие стилистику и ухудшающие читабельность.

**Снимки с разрешением один метр обеспечивают нужную достоверность изображения.**

Answer (score 0):

Хорошее разрешение снимков (не хуже 1 м) гарантирует высокую достоверность.

Answer (score 0):

**Снимки с разрешением не хуже чем один метр (не хуже 1 метра), что гарантирует высокую достоверность изображения.**

Пример: [Рекордные по четкости снимки из космоса | yaplakal.com](http://www.yaplakal.com/forum2/topic998245.html)

Аппаратура «Геотон-Л» высокого разрешения позволяет проводить панхроматическую **съемку земной поверхности** с разрешением не хуже 1 метра.

Comment: У меня есть сомнение в корректности употребления словосочетания "достоверность изображения" в техническом смысле (в художественном аспекте это широко употребляется). Лучше говорить о достоверности _информации_, содержащейся в изображении (технически она может пониматься конкретно и отдельно оговариваться в интересующем аспекте), чем о технической достоверности изображения в целом.

Comment: Возможно, достоверность информации  - более корректное выражение,  но  в любом случае должно быть сочетание (достоверность чего-то).

Comment: Достоверность чего-либо - это о том, соответствует ли оно действительности. Возможно, качество снимков гарантирует их  достоверность (изображено именно то, что заявлено), но при чем тут "высокая"? А еще точные снимки могут подтверждать высокую достоверность какой-то гипотезы, например.